# Using a random salt in password encryption?

Tags: database, encryption, hash, passwords

I've seen a few other threads about this topic, but I can't seem to find a few answers to some questions involving the use of a **random salt** in password encryption. To my understanding, the steps go something like this:

1. Generate a random salt for the user.
2. Append the salt to their password.
3. Use something like SHA-2 to hash the result.
4. Store both the salt and hashed password in the database.

How does this method work when retrieving the user's password and verifying log-in? One response says that the user's salt should be retrieved, appended to their inputted password, hashed, and then compared to the stored hash, but doesn't this raise some issues? Namely:

- How do you retrieve the salt without compromising that user? If someone wanted to brute-force a certain account's password, wouldn't they be able to retrieve the salt that was sent back from the server to hash the inputted password, thereby eliminating the security that having a salt adds?
- If we avoid the previous problem by doing the salt retrieval server-side, then won't we be sending the user's inputted password unencrypted at one point or another (so that it may later be appended to the retrieved salt)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The salt should never be exposed outside of the service - your instinct is right that this would be exposing the salt and introducing risk.

Any communication between your client and server should occur over an SSL connection - or at least using some kind of encryption of the interaction.

Keep in mind the purpose of the salt: to make it harder for someone to precalculate hash codes and therefore be able to look up passwords in the case of the database being compromised. An 8 bit salt makes the hash space 256 times bigger, making precalculation that much harder. The salt isn't about securing communication - there are other solutions for that.

Comment: The system should be secure even if the salting algorithm is exposed. What you propose is "security through obscurity", and it was never safe. All good algorithms for encription are safe even when you know them.

Comment: @ruslik Sorry, I don't get your point. Of course the algorithm should be exposed - that's axiomatic of good security. By "the salt" I meant the actual salt value for a specific password, not the salting algorithm.

Comment: @Bevan Sorry, but there is no difference.

Comment: @ruslik My understanding (always subject to correction) is that the salt acts to provide additional key bits, and like any symmetric key, should remain confidential. Wikipedia agrees ("For best security, the salt value is kept secret." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). What do you think I'm missing?

Comment: @Bevan in my inderstanding, you cannot keep it secret if the algorithm is exposed (assuming it can be generated on client's machine).

Comment: @ruslik I think I see where you're going. If you know the inputs AND the algorithm, you can generate the output, so the output can't be a secret. That's true - if you know both the salt and the password, you can generate the salted-hash, no problem. The goal of the salt, though, is to make reversal harder: If you have the salted-hash, how do you obtain the password? Without a salt, there's only one hash for a given password, so you can precalculate it. With an 8 bit salt, there are 256 salted-hashes for each password, requiring more space fore precalculation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use random salt because of goal of using it is protecting against some types of attacks such as dictionary attack, brute-force attack and rainbow attack. thus it's so important to generate random salt for each password and store hashed password and salt in user  table or attached to user profile. When you want to validate user password it's enough to hash entered password with stored salt and compare with stored hash value. I don't believe @cherouvim advise because it seems he doesn't care about above attacks. For more information i suggest an amazing, simple and understandable article by [Defuse Security](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Good luck.

Comment: 1. Create Random Salt For Each User
2. Encrypt Password With That Salt
3. Store Password in db
4. Encrypt Salt with fixed common salt, saved in your config file.
5. Store Encrypted Salt in DB.

Answer (score 1):

I use a fixed salt (for all passwords) which is hardcoded on the application code. Assuming that the salt cannot be exposed (e.g via the UI of the application) this looks simple and good enough.

Comment: The thing is, for something like a website, hard-coding the salt doesn't work for one of two reasons: a) if the salt is added client-side, it's openly visible to anyone and so it's completely useless, b) if it's done server side, it necessitates that the user's password is sent unencrypted so that it may be done server-side, and so there's a gaping flaw in either case.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think it's best to salt on the server side and use https for the client when transmitting the password.

Comment: But this means that an attacker can attack all passwords in parallel, if the hashed passwords are compromised - the very thing salting is meant to prevent. I.e. with per-user salt, then each hash computation can only be compared against that users hash result. But with a single salt for the application, every hash result can be compared against all users. And, if the hashes are exposed, two different users can determine that they have the same password.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you mean if the salt & the hashed passwords are compromised. If the attacker gains access to the server (in order to locate the salt via reverse engineering your application code) then you've also got other problems to worry about :)

Comment: @cherouvim - it's still possible for a user to determine that someone else shares the same password, without compromising the salt. If that other user is an admin, that could be a concern. And you're not meant to *have* to hide the salt. And what if they retrieve the salt, say, by an inadvertent release of your source code, rather than a server compromise? You can't change the salt without invalidating everyone's passwords.

Comment: Damien touched on something very important here which is what salts actually protect against - a preimage attack (by making in computation infeasible). Preimage attacks occur when a hacker can pregenerate a list of hashes so he has a list of known pass/hash combos. Thus when the attacker gets a hold of your hashes he is able to distinguish the passwords of any user in your database that has the same hash as any in his existing list without even brute forcing anything. The way to protect against this is salting each password with a different unique value.

Comment: To add to the above, this relates to the OP because if the db has the same salt for every user in the application, all the attacker has to do is compromise that single salt to be able to generate the entire hash list. Also, since at that point we assume the hacker has already accessed the hashes through the DB it is not a long stretch to say he can get the salt(s). The thing that makes unique salts viable is not that it's hard to get them, it's that using the unique salts to generate the predefined list of hashes would be exponentially harder as the size of the salt grows (2^n).

Answer (score 1):

Security introduced by salt is that you obtain hash for something much bigger and non-standard than the plain password. It doesn't matter if its algorithm is closed, because it protects the hash stored in plain in database from rainbow or dictionary attacks.

It's also reccomended to take hash several times recursively, maybe readding the salt at each iterations, so that brute force will take much longer.

EDIT: to what Bevan said about communication: usually the "number used once" (NONCE) scheme is used to transmit passwords over unsecure channels. The server gives a random string never used before to the client, he appends it to the plain password, computes hash, and sends it. This protects you from eavesdropping attacks.

Comment: But if the salt is fixed or the algorithm is closed, then can't something like a dictionary attack overcome that by simply appending that known salt to each of the attempts?

Comment: Well, it's not so difficult to RE the algorithm, so don't feel safe just because it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not send an unencrypted value which can be used to log in is to use SSL.  If the hash gets sent to the server, the hash itself can be sniffed and used to log in.  Do it server side.

+1 to what ruslik said about the salt.  It prevents dictionary/rainbow attacks.  A rainbow table for an average password + several bytes of random binary data would be astronomically huge.

Comment: + it will not exist already. Rainbow tables for common hash functions and common words and/or words o a certain size already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing passwords protects against plainly visible passwords, and salting them guards against dictionary attacks. As far as protecting passwords during transport, I would recommend SSL/TLS.

Comment: Props to you on this simple but perfectly correct answer. People complicate things too much with salting - it's one purpose is to protect against dictionary ("preimage") attacks and nothing more. People often think that the added length of the salt adds some sort of security which isnt true, and they also mistakenly often assume that if the salt and hashes have been compromised it is equal to not using salts at all, which is also not the case. Even with both the salts and the hashes, this adds an extreme amount of computation to have to test each salt against each word in your dictionary!